# using count value in where clause of prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to create a statement that will return the count of `event_target` grouped by (`username, event_title, and event_target`) and ordered by that count.

In other words, `totalsum` is the count of rows where (`username, event_title, and event_target`) are all the same values.

Problem is the result is not ordered in DESC by totalsum.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(`event_target`) 'totalsum' FROM `testdb` WHERE `account_id` = ? GROUP BY `username`, `event_title`, `event_target` ORDER BY 'totalsum' DESC");
```

$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['account_id']));

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//print out the array echo '<pre>',print_r($results,true),'</pre>';
```

Secondly, I would also like to use the `totalsum` value in my WHERE clause... so say I only want to return value where totalsum = 6.  This returns an empty array.  There ARE results with a totalsum = 6 if I use the above statement without this WHERE clause.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(`event_target`) 'totalsum' FROM `testdb` WHERE `account_id` = ? AND 'totalsum' = 6 GROUP BY `username`, `event_title`, `event_target` ORDER BY 'totalsum' DESC");
```

$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['account_id']));

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//print out the array echo '<pre>',print_r($results,true),'</pre>';
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the clarification on this!  This seems to work best for me at the moment.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`event_target`) `totalsum` FROM `testdb` WHERE `account_id` = ?
  GROUP BY `username`, `event_title`, `event_target` HAVING `totalsum`=6
```

I have run into another problem.  The reason I was asking about a condition for `totalsum` was this is a modification to a search function.  So... a typical search query might be something like this :

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`event_target`) `totalsum` FROM `testdb` WHERE `account_id` = ?
  AND (`event_target` LIKE 'searchquery' OR `event_title` LIKE 'searchquery' OR `event_name` LIKE 'searchquery')
  GROUP BY `username`, `event_title`, `event_target` ORDER BY `totalsum` DESC
```

How can I add in an or condition for `totalsum`?  This is probably a poor example, but say someone searches for '6' then any result with a `totalsum` with a 6 in the value should be returned as well.  In a perfect world I would like to be able to do :

```
OR `totalsum` LIKE 'searchquery'
```

Comment: What about HAVING clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong kind of quotes for `totalsum`:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`event_target`) 'totalsum' FROM `testdb` WHERE `account_id` = ? GROUP BY `username`, `event_title`, `event_target` ORDER BY 'totalsum' DESC
```

should be:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`event_target`) `totalsum` FROM `testdb` WHERE `account_id` = ? GROUP BY `username`, `event_title`, `event_target` ORDER BY `totalsum` DESC
```

although here you could leave them out if you wanted to.

To filter the results by `totalsum`, you can do something like:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`event_target`) `totalsum` FROM `testdb` WHERE `account_id` = ?
  GROUP BY `username`, `event_title`, `event_target` HAVING `totalsum`=6
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
    *,
    COUNT(`event_target`) 'totalsum' 
FROM 
    `testdb` 
WHERE 
    `account_id` = ? 
GROUP BY 
    `username`,
    `event_title`,
    `event_target`
HAVING 
    COUNT(`event_target`) = 6 
ORDER BY
    'totalsum' DESC
```

Comment: Learned something new... would something like `HAVING COUNT(`event_target`) LIKE somevalue` work as well?

Comment: hum you are comparing an INT using LIKE,
you'd better use `HAVING COUNT(event_target) BETWEEN 5 AND 7`